# Calculating svg transform values for zooming-in and dragging an image

Tags: math, svg, slider, coordinates, zooming

We have available svg area of 1300x620px, wanting to vertically and horizontally center 300x500px image with ability to zoom in and out, with default zoom level of 3.

We start by calculating the image size by dividing the available area size by the default zoom level, ending with 433x207px image, which we wrap in a `<g>` tag with `transform="translate(0,0) scale(3)"` and the result looks like that:[image]

The question is, how to calculate the proper x and y here `translate(x, y) scale(3.5)` so that the image is still centered.

The second question is, how to calculate minimum and maximum x,y coordinates of the image.

The idea is to implement sliders for the x and y axis and 2 buttons to zoom-in / zoom-out which will modify the `transform()` values for the slider functionality, but we need to know the min-max values on each axis as well as to properly transform the image so that it keeps to be centered no matter of the current transform applied.

Comment: What have you written so far? Because there's a fair number of tutorials on how to do this kind of thing on the web, including a bunch of off-the-shelf libraries that'll just do this for you, so where did you concretely get stuck? Can  you show your code? (in [MCVE] form, as runnable snippet?)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I've updated the question with a link to GitHub repo of the current state of the mini-app I'm playing with. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please note links in posts should be [in addition to showing the code](/help/how-to-ask). All the details need to be here, even if you link out to something more elaborate for folks who want more details than are necessary. Run through the [mcve] exercise, during which you may very well solve the problem all on your own (that's the whole point of the exercise =) but if you don't, you now have the appropriate code for putting in your post.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks for your feedback. That's the bare minimum of the code showing the misplaced image and the scrollbars which probably needs a different formula than the one I'm using atm. I've provided a demo snippet in the question.

Comment: Please turn that into a runnable snippet in your post, though (after further reducing, because this is definitely not a [mcve] yet, there's still quite a bit of code in your demo that is not directly related to showing off the problem).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I've updated the CodeSandbox link reducing the code even more, but because of the `Scroll` component I can't embed it as a runnable snippet here...

Comment: You'd think, but you don't _need_ scrolling, just need to trigger the zoom function, "mouse scrolling" is technically irrelevant. Instead, add just one button that calls the zoom function with some hard-coded coordinate, and done, the point is to show off the problem, not the entire UX chain that gets you to that problem. (understanding what a [mcve] really means is important. Take the human out of the problem, make code do what needs to happen, and make that happen as directly as possible: a function call that calls another function is at least 1 function call too many =)

Comment: *Actually* it's a programming question without being a coding question. One doesn't need a single [LoC](https://i1.wp.com/www.startupdaily.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/luxfon.com-18586.jpg) at all, just [PnP](https://www.uml.edu/images/math-problem-close-up-pen-paper-1400-opt_tcm18-198404.jpg).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, the zooming on the center of the image works fine. My troubles starts when I want to implement the scrolling with the sliders (or by dragging the image around), that's why I *need* them in this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll list the principal calculation in pseudocode first, and than demonstrate its functioning graphically. Finally we'll sum up things.

#### Calculus

So according to your description we start with:

```
// SVG viewport size
set viewWidth = 1300px;
set viewHeight = 620px;

// initial scale factor and according image size
set initScale = 3;
set imgWidth = viewWidth / initScale;
set imgHeight = viewHeight / initScale;
```

To adjust the position of your image we have to apply a factor to the image size:

```
set newScale = 3.5;
set adjustFactor = 0.5 * (1 - newScale / initScale);
scale(newScale);
translate(adjustFactor * imgWidth, adjustFactor * imgHeight);
```

When zooming in, e.g. with `newScale = 3.5`, we get (rounded):

```
scale(3.5);
translate(-36, -17);
```

Now lets zoom out (rounded again):

```
scale(2.5);
translate(36, 17);
```

That behavior is to be expected. To center we have to left-/up-shift when zooming in, and right-/down-shift when zooming out.

#### Scheming

**Fig.1** illustrates what is done here. We have a grayisch square within a `10 x 6 px` "canvas". We have a frame of the same size, which remains unchanged and shall always show the square centered, no matter how we scale the canvas (together with the square). Now, when scaling up the canvas without an adjusting translation, the canvas slips out of the frame, and we see only the top-left corner of the square. Using the above formula and the resulting adjustment factor of `0.5` we push the canvas back by `-5px` along the x-axis and `-3px` along the y-axis till the square is centered within the frame again.

[image: adjustment]
**Fig.1** Adjusting the position of an image slippen out of the frame by scaling, to be shown centered in that frame.

The coordinates are correspondingly:

```
minX = adjustFactor * imgWidth;
maxX = minX + imgWidth * (newScale / initScale);

minY = adjustFactor * imgHeight;
maxY = minY + imgHeight * (newScale / initScale);
```

The max-Values are basically min-Value plus newly scaled width resp. height.

#### Crunching

Note that

```
maxX = minX + imgWidth * (newScale / initScale)
     = adjustFactor * imgWidth + imgWidth * (newScale / initScale)
     = imgWidth * (adjustFactor + newScale / initScale)
     = imgWidth * (0.5 * (1 - newScale / initScale) + newScale / initScale)
     = imgWidth * (0.5 - 0.5 * newScale / initScale + newScale / initScale)
     = imgWidth * (0.5 + 0.5 * newScale / initScale)
     = imgWidth * 0.5 * (1 + newScale / initScale)
```

Remembers of something, doesn't it?

```
adjustFactor = 0.5 * (1 - newScale / initScale);
```

It's just a plus instead of a minus. The difference between `0.5 * (1 + newScale / initScale)` and `0.5 * (1 - newScale / initScale)` is `newScale / initScale`. We may want to consider this, as divisions are costly concerning performance. The less the better.

#### Mopping Up

So in total we get:

```
set a = 0.5 * (1 - newScale / initScale); // our former "adjustFactor"
set b = a + newScale / initScale;

set minX = a * imgWidth;
set maxX = b * imgWidth;

set minY = a * imgHeight;
set maxY = b * imgHeight;

scale(newScale);
translate(minX, minY);  // looks sane, right?
```

You can use the min/max-values for scrolling checks. It might make sense to turn off scrolling for an axis when the respective min-value is `>= 0`.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough analysis of the problem and the detailed explanation of the solution. I'm hiding the slider if the zoom level is not more than 3, but checking the min-value is a good alternative as well. Cheers.

Comment: how the formulas will change if we don't want to zoom to the very center of the image, but on a defined point, like for example [imgWidth-10 , imgHeight - 10]  ?

Comment: Just "re-center" the image *before* all the calculations by `translate(newCenterX - imgWidth/2, newCenterY - imgHeight/2)`, so in your example it would be `translate(imgWidth/2 - 10, imgHeight/2 - 10)`. That approach would keep the shifting and the zooming apart. Alternatively one can of course fuse the transform matrices of both into one operation. I'll take a look at that later and update my post correspondingly.

Comment: That doesn't work, probably I didn't explained properly what I'm trying to achieve. Currently, when using the formulas from your answer and we zoom-in, the result is zoomed image exactly on the center. What I'm trying to achieve is to point the mouse somewhere in the image, and after the zooming whatever has been pointed to stay where the mouse is. I've tried to calculate how far the mouse is from the center and to adjust the `translate()` with the result, but it's not accurate.

Comment: So, lets say you point the mouse on a red dot at (x, y) in "canvas coords" then after zooming the red dot has still to be exactly at the same (x, y), i.e. there's no re-centering on that red dot (resp. the red dot doesn't "move" to the canvas' center) as I did assume?

Comment: Exactly. I'm trying to achieve that red dot to stay in-place after the zooming. Will be super grateful if you can help me out with a formula or directions how to achieve this effect. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Trying to compensate with the mouse delta to the center was wrong idea. I did it by calculating where exactly the mouse is located before the zoom as percentage of the scaled width/height for the X and Y axis, then after the zooming, using the percentages and the new image dimensions, it was possible to calculate the proper `translate()` values to keep the image aligned just below the mouse. Thank you once again for your detailed explanation on the initial problem, it helped me a lot!

Comment: It was my pleasure. And I'm glad you could solve also your additional "mousy" problem ;-)